# How to host a java application (without using webservices)

Tags: java, swing, hosting

I made a game with sockets that works fine on my machine, and now I would like to run the server on a host so that anyone can join in at any time.
All I'm finding are services for web applications, mine is just a swing application that can run by itself.
What kind of server can I use (instead of my own machine)? Would I need to change the code or is it possible to just find a host that runs my server application as is?

Also, note that for now I kept it simple, there is no data storage.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Amazon EC2 cloud.  Essentially what you're looking to do is acquire a public IP address (an be done from the Amazon EC2 admin console).  You'll be installing java and then opening a port in your security settings to allow traffic to whatever port your game server is running on.

EC2 is free for low volumes of usage for the first year (new accounts only) and I've had fairly good luck with them in terms of downtime and affordability.

Comment: "what you're looking to do is acquire a public IP address " This is indeed what I want. All I want to do is to change the IP of my socket (which is currently on localhost), there must be an easy solution to that, surely? Your suggestion seems way too complicated for what I need (many softwares to install, code to change, etc).

Comment: Are you trying to host this from your home?  You indicate "anyone can join at any time", which I assume implies the world-wide-web.  Your home IP address changes, you have a firewall, and cable providers tend to frown on home internet lines providing inbound listening ports.  Many providers deliver hardware that has built in firewalls which do not even allow this.